# How do I recreate a dynamic url?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Preface: I'm new to anything to do with html/web programming and scraping.

For fun, I've been playing around with Scrapy and want to try to log into an account online and scrape fantasy football scores. The page is http://www.espn.com/fantasy and the page source with the relevant link is:

```
<a data-affiliatename="espn" data-language="en" data-regformid="espn_bbc" tref="/members/v3_1/login" data-behavior="overlay" data-route="false" href="#" class="med button-alt sign-in">Log In</a>
```

Clicking on this calls some Javascript (I think) and generate an xhr request that looks like this (from looking at the network tab in firebug):

```
http://log.go.com/log?action_name=api%3Alaunch%3Alogin&anon=true&appid=DTSS-DISNEYID-UI&client_id=ESPN-FANTASYLM-PROD&conversation_id=de122753-f2d4-4988-a928-a0508dc1369e&correlation_id=dedc6867-eb52-4a5f-a8b7-ea6b44a723a3&os=Ubuntu%20undefined&process_time=11454&sdk_version=Web%202.19.9&success=true&swid=c1b300b5-ec07-4d08-8813-c4f501e9d593&timestamp=2016-09-06T00%3A27%3A23.671Z
```

From the network requests/responses in firebug, I gather that this is calling an api to launch the login overlay and there are a number of parameters, like conversation_id, correlation_id, timestamp, etc.

Questions:

1. I believe I found the swid in a cookie, but how do I generate the conversation and correlation IDs?
2. Are the timestamp or any of the other parameters optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1: Scrapy manages cookies by itself, unless the cookie is complicated and is modified by javascript(which is very unlikely) you don't need to do anything. Regarding whether url parameter was generated from your cookie is also quite unlikely, it's probably just a coincidence and both cookie and url parameter use some `<input>` data from html source.

Regarding #2: there is no way of knowing whether an url parameter is required or optional other than experimenting by changing/deleting it.

You should be able to retrieve majority if not all post request form data by using `FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=<your custom value dict>)`. [More about FormRequest on official docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest)